# AJAX function triggers once but not a second time when using buttons in dynamically generate tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an issue where I'm trying to cause an event to delete an element. This delete event applies to element that is clicked and an object above it. The following ajax call works when applied to a button that doesn't change but only works when the page is freshly reloaded when applied to the buttons I want it applied to.

```
/discards a card based upon what button is pressed 
$(".discardCard").on('click',function(){ 
    //alert('button linked') //buttons are linked no longer need
    playerid = $(this).attr("data-xml");
    dCard = $(this).attr("dCard");
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "discardCard.php", 
    data: {player: playerid, dCard:dCard}, 
    success: function(msg){ 
        //alert('ajax function starts');
        $('#playerHands').html(msg);
        //alert('ajax function finishes')
    }
    });
    //alert('1');
});
//alert('2');
```

The following shows what I intend to have the event do. The process to obtain the shown result was: click Discard 1, refresh page, click Discard 2.

edit! I need more rep to post a photo with this, but you can see it here:
http://i963.photobucket.com/albums/ae118/Akado117/Untitled_zps56a2159c.png.

Answer (score 0):

When you get new HTML, you need to make it clickable the same way you made the old HTML clickable... i.e. you need to do `.on()` on it.

```
function clickDiscard () { 
    playerid = $(this).attr("data-xml");
    dCard = $(this).attr("dCard");
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "discardCard.php", 
        data: {player: playerid, dCard:dCard}, 
        success: function(msg){  
            $('#playerHands').html(msg);
            // remove existing bindings to avoid double binding...
            $(".discardCard").off("click");
            $(".discardCard").on("click", clickDiscard);
        }
    });
}

$(".discardCard").on("click", clickDiscard);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the help! What does: $(".discardCard").off("click"); do?